# Identification of a very strange SMD component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, line

Could anyone help me identify what component this is? It is the white component with a black stripe.

What ever it is, it appears to be a open circuit. I couldn't measure any resistance (or capacitance). One pin of the connection has DC voltage while the second pin has 0 DC voltage.

(Also the backside of the component is plain white, not sure if it helps but just in case)

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: That is very odd indeed. There are no reference designators either making it harder to interpret. If I had to guess, it's just a simple wire.

Comment: Black is zero on the resistor colour code. Is it an SMD zero ohm resistor?

Comment: What is the function of the board?

Comment: I'm wondering if it is (or was) a fuse. There looks to be back-to-back diodes or similar in series with it. Is it part of something like a voltmeter that's frequently subjected to abuse?

Comment: Isn't this the resistor mounted upside down mistakenly?

Comment: @KingDuken It can not be a wire because DC voltage cannot be seen on both sides.

Comment: @Transistor It can not be a zero ohm resistor because with the voltmeter it's seem to be open circuit and no resistance can be measured.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I also thought that it may be a diode but I couldn't find any off the shelf diode looks even similar to this component.
@ KevinWhite It is a preamplifier circuit.
@ VillageTech No it can't be as I said the backside of the component is plain white, no marks, nothing.

Comment: How exotic is this preamplifier?  Is it possible it's a very high value resistor (eg. 1G)?  If you have a meter with conductivity function you may be able to measure it.

Comment: @xydn - As highlighted in an [earlier comment from *Spehro*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475091/identification-of-a-very-strange-smd-component#comment1204238_475091), surrounding components might give us some clues. Personally, I want to see added to the question: (a) more photos of the PCB, showing the whole PCB from different angles, with any known info annotated (e.g. which connectors lead to power, signals etc.); (b) any reverse-engineering of the schematic done so far; (c) more context e.g. if you're trying to repair the pre-amp, perhaps the component has changed value

Comment: Given the black line, maybe a zero-ohm resistor? Compare with marking of THR zero-ohm resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, my best guess is, that this is a some base material (white) with a conductive ink (black) drawn on top of it. I also used the fact, that the black part covers the soldering on both ends (to ensure connection).
If this is true, the resistance between the two pads should be less than 1 Ohm. Can you verify this with an ohmmeter?

Comment: It could be a carbon(?) printed resistor of some sort, but the resistance could be nearly arbitrary IMO, not at all necessarily less than 1 Ohm.

Comment: As I said, with the ohmmeter it seem to be open circuit. Can't obtain any resistance value. Since it is open circuit, it can not be a resistor less than 1 Ohm.

Comment: Yes, got you on this. As @Richard the Space cat correctly added, it might be an arbitrary resistance